# MYSQL Data Mismatch Due to Missing Dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table named customers which has the following columns

```
msisdn BIGINT 20
join_date DATETIME
```

The msisdn is a unique value to identify customers.

There is a second table named ws_billing_all which has the following structure

```
id  INTEGER  11 (Primary Key)
msisdn BIGINT 20
event_time DATETIME
revenue INTEGER
```

With the help of someone on this site, I have the following query which I'm using to determine the amount of revenue generated after 30 days from all customers that joined on a given day. So that output looks something like this

```
JoinedOn     TotalCustomers        TotalRevenue (after 30 days)
Dec 1         150                  21,394   (up to Dec 31)
Dec 2          45                   4,182   (up to Jan 1)
Dec 3          83                   6,829   (up to Jan 2)
```

The query I'm using is as follows;

```
SELECT date(c.join_date) JoinedOn,
       count(c.msisdn) TotalCustomers,
       SUM(w.revenue) TotalRevenue
FROM customers c
JOIN ws_billing_all w 
ON c.msisdn = w.msisdn
AND date(w.event_time ) <= date_add(c.join_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY )
where c.join_date >= 20071129000000
group by date( c.join_date )
order by date( c.join_date )
```

So the query generates the correct revenue but the total customers figure was incorrect. I eventually that the reason for this (I believe) is that the there are some dates in customers in which no customers joined and that this is causing the incorrect data.

Can anyone suggest how I can generate the correct data considering there are dates missing in customers?

Comment: maybe u need count(distinct c.msisdn) TotalCustomers,

Comment: What exactly do you want in the column TotalCustomers? Right now it looks like you get the number that joined on a specific date (first column).

Comment: @Haim All the msisdn's are distinct but I have tried that

Comment: @Smalcat, TotalCustomers are all msisdn's seen for the first time on a date (JoinedOn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it...  it might be that its due to not all customers who have joined actually placed orders, so they are being excluded... change to a LEFT JOIN to the billing table

```
FROM customers c
   LEFT JOIN ws_billing_all w
```

Comment: The problem is that when I use LEFT JOIN, the query just runs for hours

Comment: I think I managed to speed up the LEFT JOIN via indexes and now the data is correct. Thanks again